# java calling method before super

Tags: java, constructor, super

Assuming I have a super class that has 3 parameters in it's constructor and i am inheriting this class that also has a constructor with 3 parameters, and I want to call the super class constructor but before I want to do some logic on the sub class first, I can call a static method that receives those 3 parameters but I have to return only one, so this is the solution I came up with

```
public class someClass extends  SuperClass {
    public someClass(int a,int b,int c) {
         super(func(a,b,c),b,c);
    }
    public static int func(int a,int b,int c){
        //usage a b c
        return a;
    }
}
```

It seems a bit ugly and I was wondering if there is a better solution to use the parameters myself and then call super regularly. Note that i cannot change the Super class or that usages of the sub classes and therefore factory Design Pattern

Comment: ... you're aware that a constructor shouldn't really contain 'logic', right? so, if I understand this correctly: you want to run business logic on an object that isn't even completely instantiated?

Comment: Does your `func` method always return `a` (which means the super call would always be `super(a,b,c)`? If that's the case, I see no reason of calling `func` before `super(a,b,c)`.

Comment: I want to call to external logic like opening a file, which is not fully related to the object itself i'm instantiated

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I understand correctly what you're trying to do, but what about the Builder pattern? you could perform your logic before calling the constructor that way.

Comment: @Turing85 Absolutely not! Please take a look at their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This is example code, highly illegal at Code Review.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the logic out of your constructor, you can easily create a factory method in your subclass:

```
public class SomeClass extends SuperClass {
    private SomeClass(int a, int b, int c) {
        super(a, b ,c);
    }

    public static SomeClass create(int a, int b, int c){
        // calculate a for constructor

        return new SomeClass(a, b, c);
    }
}
```

Then you can create instances as follows:

```
SomeClass someClass = SomeClass.create(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Users of this class won't be aware of the method create, I can't change the way users use this class (they will use the static type of SuperClass) : i.e. I cant force the users to use `SomeClass someClass = SomeClass.create(1, 2, 3);`

Comment: If they use the static type of `SuperClass`, how can they create instances of `SomeClass`? Are you using reflection?

Comment: there is a list of class files that a method receives and creates an instance of each one into a list of SuperClass, I add a class file to this list.

Comment: From what you describe, the code smells because the design smells. If you're unable or unwilling to change the design, I guess you'll just have to live with the smell...

Answer (score 4):

In Java you are not allowed to execute another statement before the call to `super`. The trick you mentioned works, but you cannot refactor your code to have the call to `func` in a statement before the call to `super`.

In my experience, issues like this often hint at some design issue. Maybe you can solve the underlying problem by re-thinking about the responsibilities of the two involved classes.

Comment: `func` does need to be `static`. You cannot call instance methods from the constructor before the call to `super`.

Comment: **issues like this often hint at some design issue** +1

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the builder pattern

```
public class SomeClass extends SuperClass {
    public static class Builder {
        private int a, b, c;
        public Builder withA(int a) { 
            this.a = a;
            return this;
        }
        public Builder withB(int b) { ... }
        public Builder withC(int c) { ... }
        public SomeClass build() {
            // logic goes here
            return new SomeClass(...)
        }
    }

    // hide this from public use, use Builder instead
    protected SomeClass(int a, int b, int, c) {
        super(a, b, c);
    }
}

SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass.Builder().
    withA(1).
    withB(2).
    withC(3).
    build();
```